# Stripe Subscription: Change Date of Next Billing?

Tags: stripe-payments

Let's say I have a subscriber that started a monthly subscription on January 1, 2022 for 12 months, recurring, and is scheduled to billed again on January 1, 2023.

Assume I wanted to be generous and extend that subscriber's subscription by a month. Is there a way to tell Stripe to bill the subscriber on February 1, 2023 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely need to set the billing cycle anchor to the desired future date by introducing a [trial period](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#using-a-trial-to-change-the-billing-cycle).

Comment: Reviewing. Seems promising.